# Unable to resolve unmet dependencies for GUI - linux 20.04.1

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, gui

I have been trying to install a GUI on my Linux server, but I have been unable to, due to unmet dependencies.

When I try to install Gnome, I get:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-appindicator but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: language-selector-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-desktop-minimal but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-manager but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: yelp but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: zenity but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: apport-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: bluez-cups but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: cheese but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: cups but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: cups-bsd but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: cups-client but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: eog but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gedit but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-calendar but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-characters but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-getting-started-docs but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-initial-setup but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-todo but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: hplip but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ibus but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ibus-table but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libproxy1-plugin-gsettings but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: orca but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: printer-driver-c2esp but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: printer-driver-ptouch but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: printer-driver-splix but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: shotwell but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: totem but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-docs but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: usb-creator-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have run `sudo apt-get update` and everything is up to date. Trying other GUI installations are also coming up with the same problems. Like, openbox, where I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xorg : Depends: xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+19ubuntu14)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried a number of fixes and nothing works. I have also tried installing via tasksel, but it still does not work. I have tried all the fixes on this page:https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/ and those on this page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389156/how-to-fix-held-broken-packages.
Nothing has worked. No packages are returned when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Can someone help?